# How to publish Boost Unit Test results into TFS 2010

Tags: unit-testing, boost

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best option to publish boost unit test results into a TFS 2010 system.  I know the boost test results have to be exported into xml format and then this xml file has to be transformed to the MSUnit trx format.  Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Best regards,
Victor D.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a test project with a 'generic test' that calls your own test, you can publish that into TFS. This is probably the simplest way.